# printf не выводит значения переменных типа long

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    long num, temp;
    temp=1;
    num=1;
    for(i=0; num>0 ; num<<=1, i++);
    for(num = 0; i>0; temp<<=1, i--)
    {
        num |= temp;
    }
    printf("%ld\n", LONG_MAX);
    printf("%ld", num);
    return 0;
 }
```

Собственно задача: написать вывод максимального значения типов. С `short` и `int` проблем не возникает, но вот тип `long` не выводит, выводит только то что помещается в `int`.

Comment: а вы уверены что в вашем компиляторе `sizeof(int) != sizeof(long)`?

Comment: Кажется не весь код, который вы запостили, относится к вопросу.

Comment: Деиствительно int == long

Answer (score 3):

Собственно код:

```c
printf(" SHRT_MAX: %hi\n", SHRT_MAX);
printf("  INT_MAX: %i\n", INT_MAX);
printf(" LONG_MAX: %li\n", LONG_MAX);
printf("LLONG_MAX: %lli\n", LLONG_MAX);
```

На моей машине (*GNU/Linux*, 64-битный):

```
 SHRT_MAX: 32767
  INT_MAX: 2147483647
 LONG_MAX: 9223372036854775807
LLONG_MAX: 9223372036854775807
```

Если у вас не так, смотрите `sizeof` типов.

Дополнительно, вы можете воспользоваться типами фиксированной длины,
например `int32_t`, из заголовка
`<inttypes.h>`:

```c
printf(" INT8_MAX: %" PRIi8 "\n", INT8_MAX);
printf("INT16_MAX: %" PRIi16 "\n", INT16_MAX);
printf("INT32_MAX: %" PRIi32 "\n", INT32_MAX);
printf("INT64_MAX: %" PRIi64 "\n", INT64_MAX);
```

```
 INT8_MAX: 127
INT16_MAX: 32767
INT32_MAX: 2147483647
INT64_MAX: 9223372036854775807
```

Заметьте использование предопределённых макросов
`PRI{fmt}{size}` и конкатенации строчных литералов.

Comment: Пробую просмотреть, а printf не знает не ld ни lld, попробую поискать другой компилятор.

Comment: @ВячеславЛогиновский  У вас не _Windows_ ли?  _MSVC_ тот ещё зверь.  Не удивлюсь, если там `<inttypes.h>` нету вообще.

Comment: Да винда)) Сейчас попробую на виртуалке разверну linux и проверю там

Comment: <inttypes.h> есть.

Comment: Компилятор стоит MinGW 64 битный, поэтому и удивляюсь, что такая подстава с long. Проверил double через сайз оф он 64 бита, а лонг 32

Comment: Цитата из https://stackoverflow.com/a/7607557/1892060: «*MSVC (and the ABI used by Windows) defines `long` to be 32 bits wide, and MingW follows suit because well, the compiler is a lot more useful when it agrees with the host OS*».

Comment: В моей системе лонг равен инт оказался, попробовал проверить long long, вот он 64 битный.

Answer (score 2):

[Какой формат команды printf соответствует типу long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561/what-is-the-argument-for-printf-that-formats-a-long)

В большинстве компиляторов sizeof(int) == sizeof(long).

Если у вас это не так, попробуйте использовать формат `%lld`, он соответствует 64-битному целому числу.

Также вы можете задавать количество бит в формате, например, так: `%l64d`, что будет соответствовать 64-битному целому числу.

Comment: %l48d компилятор воспринимает только l остальное видит как строку получается выводит 64d в консоль. Прошу прощения за тупняки давно не открывал си.

Comment: Хм, у меня всё в порядке, только что попробовал сделать.
В любом случае, это лишь пример

Comment: Понял ошибку свою, нет формата для 48-битного числа. Поправил ответ.

Comment: @Gordory  А разве число в глаголе форматирования не является максимальным числом символов для выравнивания и проч.?  Для строк точно.

Comment: Для целых это количество бит, вроде бы.
Смещения и прочее там по-другому задавались.